# K means plotting problems? not sure where I am going wrong, any suggestions?

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have been working with some data for quite some time now and I am trying to get 4 clusters using the k means method. I will put my code below so you can see where I am currently at. Im not sure if I missed a step or what but this is my first time doing k means clustering with python.

```
data=Bel_sort_cleaned.drop(['cprptp','JURISDICTION','STREET','ADDRESS','ddes1',                      
'DESCRIPTION','COM_BLDG_VALUE','OCCUPANCY','segments','OBJECTID'], axis=1)
data=data.dropna()

X=data.values.reshape(-1,1)
y=data['HOUSENUM'].values,reshape(-1,1)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0).fit(X)

label = kmeans.fit_predict(X)

plt.scatter(X[label==0, 0], X[label==0, 1], s=100, c='red', label ='Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(X[label==1, 0], X[label==1, 1], s=100, c='blue', label ='Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(X[label==2, 0], X[label==2, 1], s=100, c='green', label ='Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(X[albel==3, 0], X[label==3, 1], s=100, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 4')
```

the original data was loaded in earlier in my file which is where the 'Bel_sort_cleaned' came from.

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated, As I am pretty stuck.

I am currently getting an Indexerror

Comment: The error message is fairly informative: the X matrix doesn't have two columns after you reshape it. Check with `data.values.reshape(-1,1).shape`. So you can't do this: `X[label==i, 1]`.

Comment: So what should I change it too?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with how you preprocess the input features *X* before clustering but python stumbles upon the problem only when you attempt to plot the clusters.

So split the analysis in two parts: 1) clustering, 2) visualization. And make sure that part 1) works as intended before moving onto part 2).

Let's make this answer reproducible by providing the code to generate fake data for classification.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=100,
    n_features=20, n_informative=4,
    n_classes=4, n_clusters_per_class=1,
    random_state=1234,
)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[X, y])
X.shape, y.shape, data.shape
#> ((100, 21), (100,), (100, 21))
```

Why do you flatten X? This doesn't make sense and it's where the bug occurs.

```py
X = data.values.reshape(-1, 1)
X.shape
#> (2100, 1)
```

Instead let's use all the columns in the data frame. Or even better, for your actual analysis, specify the columns to use as input features for clustering. For example, do you really want to use HOUSENUM and OBJECTID to generate the K-Means clusters?

```py
X = data.values
X.shape
#> (100, 21)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(X)
```

Check that there are 4 centroids, one for each cluster. The centroids have the same dimensions as the number of input features *X*.

```py
kmeans.cluster_centers_.shape
#> (4, 21)
```

We've checked that there are 4 clusters. Finally we are ready to plot them. And we plot them along dimensions 1 and 2, which correspond to the first two features in the feature matrix *X*.

```py
label = kmeans.predict(X)

plt.scatter(X[label == 0, 0], X[label == 0, 1], s=100, c='red', label='Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(X[label == 1, 0], X[label == 1, 1], s=100, c='blue', label='Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(X[label == 2, 0], X[label == 2, 1], s=100, c='green', label='Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(X[label == 3, 0], X[label == 3, 1], s=100, c='cyan', label='Cluster 4')
```

[image]

Comment: Small quibble: I think your example data would be better if there were 2 or 3 obvious points per cluster and the centroids were different from the data... because there are actually 6 points in your final plot, but it looks like 4 so it's easy to confuse the data with the centroids. If you see what I mean.

Comment: @kwinkunks I agree but it should be on the OP to provide the data for a minimally reproducible example. However, in a spirit of helpfulness, I've updated my answer with data generated by `sklearn.datasets.make_classification` .

Comment: Okay I have finally gotten a graph by getting rid of the reshaping so thank you. I have added my new problem to the question haha as my graph is having some problems. Any suggestions here?

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should write a new question as OS questions are intended to be stand-alone so others can benefit from them in the future.

Comment: In your new question, include a minimally reproducible example. Otherwise it's hard to guess what's going on from a plot. It can be any number of things.

Comment: Here is a guide about asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alright I have set my question back to its original statement and will write a new one. Thank you for your help.